# React-navigation with react-native: DrawerIcon not rendered if part of component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to use createDrawerNavigator with `DrawerIcon`. However, the `DrawerIcon` is only shown if set directly with the `createDrawerNavigator` function. The icons are not rendered if set in the screen component.

This works:

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    General: { screen: General },
    Business: { screen: Business },
    Entertainment: {
      screen: Entertainment,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerIcon: <Icon name="home" style={{ fontSize: 24 }} />
      }
    },
    Sports: { screen: Sports }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent
  }
);
```

But if I put the navigationOptions in the screen itself, in Entertainment screen, it does not work:

```
class EntertainmentArticleList extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = function(props) {
    return {
      // header: null
      title: "Entertainment",
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "white"
      },
      headerTitleStyle: { textAlign: "center", alignSelf: "center", flex: 1 },
      headerLeft: (
        <Icon
          name="menu"
          onPress={() => props.navigation.openDrawer()}
          style={{
            textAlign: "center",
            alignSelf: "center",
            fontSize: 24,
            marginLeft: 10
          }}
        />
      ),
      headerRight: <View />,
      drawerIcon: <Icon name="home" style={{ fontSize: 24 }} />
    };
  };
  render() {
...
```

If I do this, the drawerIcon is not shown as part of my Drawer. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are defining header properties in the navigationOptions I asume EntertainmentArticleList is also in a stackNavigator. navigationOptions only applies to it's first parent.

Without knowing the rest of your code it's hard to give any good answers but I suggest you read  [this section of the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html)

Comment: Yes, you are right, EntertainmentArticleList is in a stackNavigator. Does this mean, the stackNavigator is its first parent and the DrawerNavigator its second parent and thus the navigationOptions do not get applied to the second parent? How is this to be fixed?

Comment: Making what you describe work would include creating separate stacks for each tab screen. Nested navigators can be tricky, so unless you need to dynamically render the icon I would suggest keeping it in the createDrawerNavigator function.